# PHP Loop that is not looping

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am writing a loop that is building a table.  With a **mysql_num_row**, I get how many persons (18), and I want tables with 6 persons max (so:  `$Peoples = (mysql_num_row($SQL_statement) /6;)`.

In the loop, I increment $Count:  `$Count = $Count + 1;`

When I write:

```
Do{
  [code]
} while($Count == $Peoples);
```

The condition is not working:  after 1 loop it exits from the loop.  I printed $Count wich is 1, and $Peoples is 3.

Is there something to do with this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to use

```
Do{
  [code]
} while($Count != $Peoples);
```

(note the inequality check).

> The condition is not working: after 1 loop it exits from the loop. I
>   printed $Count wich is 1, and $Peoples is 3.

`==` is the equality operator - it checks if both sides are equal.

Your PHP code is operating correctly - you are telling the code to exit when `count` is different to `people`. `$Count wich is 1, and $Peoples is 3.` meets that criteria. The code I've posted above will continue looping while `count` is *not* equal to `people`.

Answer (score 3):

because 1 != 3.  You need while($count != $Peoples)

Or better yet, while($count < $peoples)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `do { [code] } while($Count < $Peoples)` or `do { [code] } while($Count != $Peoples)`. What your program is doing right now is adding 1 to `$Count` and then checking the loop condition. Since `$Count != $Peoples`, the loop exits.

Answer (score 1):

== is the **equals** comparison operator.  Your count will never initially equal the number of people, so your loop doesn't loop (do-while loops always execute the initial code in the do section, regardless of whether or not the loop condition is met).

What you likely need is to use the < operator, as you're incrementing your count over the life of the loop.